# Update multiple rows with sub query

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have two tables, UserStatus and User.

UserStatus has two fields: 
Username,Status

User has two fields
Username, Deleted

This is the query I'm using

```
Update users
   set deleted = '1'
where username = (select username
                    from tempDUDPIVOT 
                   where status = 'inactive')
```

but get the error:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I've tried a number of variations but can't figure out the solution... I have a feeling its very obvious.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UPDATE` syntax requires a scalar subquery. Using `EXISTS (subquery)` bring the parameters of the predicate closer together (i.e. makes the query easier to read and maintain, IMO) e.g.

```
UPDATE users 
   SET deleted = '1' 
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT *
                 FROM tempDUDPIVOT AS T1
                WHERE T1.status = 'inactive'
                      AND T1.username = users.username
              );
```

You could also use Standard SQL `MERGE` if your SQL product supports it (though note the parameters of the predicate further apart here):

```
MERGE INTO users 
   USING (
          SELECT username
            FROM tempDUDPIVOT
           WHERE status = 'inactive'
         ) AS T1 (username)
      ON T1.username = users.username
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE
      SET users.deleted = '1';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its on SQL2005 so I don't have Merge available.

Answer (score 3):

```
Update users set deleted = '1'
where username IN (select username from tempDUDPIVOT where status = 'inactive')
```

`IN` accepts `0..inf` values to be returned, and `=` accepts 1 and only one (not 0 or 42).